# How to remove easily the white areas which appears during texturing a surface with uv maps

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm attempting to make a texture for a model i've been working on, so i've been trying to get a decent UV map, However whenever I do it usually ends up either with a lot of white areas. I tried to refresh the image texture (the default grid),but they are still there. The only way I found to remove them is to rebuild the mesh in vertex mode. As you can imagine,it is a very tedious work. Do you know a way to prevent this ? I attached a picture to show you what happens. You see only one little white area because I have removed all the others ones.

[image: pic]

Comment: I don't know what does this, I don't know what you mean by "rebuilding the mesh" either, you should post a picture making your geometry clearly visible. Sometimes I get artifacts due to bad topology but mine are black. have you tried recalculating normals ?

Comment: Me too. But those white faces are not assigned the UV map image as all the others. If you select just them, the UV editor image disappears. If you delete the UV map, and rebuild it, then assign the same grid image to it, the white spots seem to disappear, and the UV image is mapped on all the mesh.

Comment: It sounds like those faces simply have a different material assigned to them. It's hard to tell with so little info. Post more screenshots with your unwrapped UV layout, your mesh in edit mode, your material setup etc. or even the blend file. It's hard to tell from that single screenshot alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those white faces appear because they are not linked to the same texture as the rest of the model. This can happen if you for example add new faces after the rest of the model has been linked to the texture. Fixing:

1. Make sure the faces which are visible as white are actually unwrapped
2. Hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces
3. In UV / Image Editor hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces
4. In the bottom of the UV / Image Editor click the *Select image* icon next to either new/open buttons or the texture name, and select the image you want to use. (even if the field shows the image already, it might not be applied to all faces)